# SQL Files and Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

So I'm kinda new with Ruby on Rails. In one of my Database classes the teacher asked us to create a simple application using any tool I liked. The app just has to have the ability to get new users, let users make appointments and add patients (it's for doctors), all that just enter information to the database and quering the database for information.

The problem is that in the specifications of this project says that every interaction with the database has to be done in "Raw SQL", so I can't use the Ruby On Rails utilities. I have been working with this framework for about six months, so I'm familiarized with it, and I know how to make the "Raw SQL" for the seeding of the database, and the queries, but I don't know how to start the project from my database.sql file, where I create the schema and all the tables.

This can be with any DBMS, I currently have a script for sql server and mysql.

How can I create my project using the sql file to create the database instead of using rails migrations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not exactly sure where you are heading with this, but my first thought was Rake.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I have a SQL script where I create the database and all the tables with their constraints and primary keys and foreign keys. How can I make rails take that script to create the database

Comment: You can `connection.execute('big pile of SQL here')` in migrations and most other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "Raw SQL" does your teacher mean *all* the SQL, including the CREATE TABLE statements? Or just the SELECT statements? You can do both, raw, in Rails, but can you use standard Rails migrations?

Rails is like learning assembler by learning C. You learn assembler better when not lost in an endless sea of it. Rails wraps up relations so you don't need to spend all day writing redundant JOIN clauses.

Here's the answer to the "raw SQL?" FAQ in Rails: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql . I would wrap that in a cute logger method that writes each SELECT statement to a formatted file, so you can turn that in as your homework. But you can tell I didn't do very well in school...

Comment: Yeah with all SQL, it means also the CREATE TABLE and the relations with de FK's and the SELECT. I can use migrations just if all the interaction is originated by the SQL scripts that I need to make manually.

Comment: Put raw SQL in the migrations too, and you are set. Also, if I were evil, I could point out you could A> write an app in raw Rails, B> capture all the SQL in the log, C> copy the SQL out and put it into `find_by_sql` statements, D> clean it up so it looks like a human wrote it, E> profit!